# Как отцентрить положение содержимого div'а, но его содержимое сделать с левым выравниванием

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, bootstrap

Нужно отцентрить положение div'а, чтобы его содержимое придерживалось левого выравнивания:
[image: контент находиться по центру, но с выравниваем по левой стороне]

Как видите контент находиться по середине, но с выравниваем по левой стороне

Comment: добавтt стилей и розметки, либо попробуйте для div'a margin: 0 auto;

Comment: добавте пожалуйста пример тут, либо на фидле либо на кодпене, так сложно что-то сказать

Comment: задача именно стоит сделать универсальным выполнение подобного

Comment: @nrjska, если вы исполузуете, какие-то стили которые влияют на общую универсальность то соответственно никакой универсальности не будет. Например: margin: 0 auto; для div'a  должен работать так ка div - это блочный елемент и он будет центрироватся, если у него нет float; либо используйте flexbox. Сложно что-то сказать не видив вашего примера на примере кода, который вы сейчас используете

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с display: inline-block

```css
.title {
  text-align: center;
}

.title-inner {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;  
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="title"><span class="title-inner">Разработка и производство <br>высоковольтного оборудования</span></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Просто margin: auto; и все

```css
.title {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">Разработка и производство <br>высоковольтного оборудования</div>
```

Comment: Мне нужно динамическое изменение положение, а в этом случае придется при смене разрешения менять параметр width

Comment: @nrjshka не придётся, с чёго бы это? Если только родитель div имеет фиксированную ширину.

Comment: это же grid сетка из bootstrap

Comment: да какая разница какой тут width. Я поставил 50%, чтобы в сниппете было видно. Внутри блока в сетке вставьте div с margin: auto, он будет позиционирован посередине этого блока, неважно какая у него ширина.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё один способ, более гибкий - flex:

```css
.title
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.title > *
{
  max-width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="title"><span>Разработка и производство <br>высоковольтного оборудования</span></div>
```